# VAG TP 2.0 complete list of AT commands

Tags: at-command, can-bus, obd-ii, elm327

I am trying to find DTCs from various ECUs in a Skoda Rapid 2009 model.
I am using OBDLink SX (elm 327 chip) and Putty (similar to HyperTerminal)

https://jazdw.net/tp20
This link gives the list of commands that I should request the ECUs of any VAG car because they run on TP 2.0 protocol. But I am unable to get any response. It always gives me 'NO DATA'. I think I am missing 'AT' commands like maybe set timeout or wakeup message.

```html
>at z 
at z 


ELM327 v2.1 



>at h1 
at h1 
OK 

>at l1 
at l1 
OK 

>at s1 
at s1 
OK 

>at pb c001 
at pb c001 
OK 

>at d1 
at d1 
OK 

>at sp b 
at sp b 
OK 

>at sh 200 
at sh 200 
OK 

>05 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
05 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
205 7 00 D0 00 03 68 07 01 

>03 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
03 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1 
203 7 00 D0 00 03 90 07 01 


>at sh 768 
at sh 768 
OK 

>at cra 300 
at cra 300 
OK 

>a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 
a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 
NO DATA 

>a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 1 
a0 0f 8a ff 32 ff 1 
NO DATA
```

Can someone help me to list the step by step commands to get VAG DTCs from engine, ABS, Airbag, EPS etc. Online resources will be helpful too.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a listing of all the terminal commands you sent to the obdlink in putty and the responses you got.

Comment: @Jonathan727 Done

Comment: Why use channel b with AT SP B?

Are you sure that you can check ABS, Airbag, ESP etc with ELM?
In the list of pids in mode 01 nothing about this sensors

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you do not have set the right protocol settings (sp / pb) to me. Are you certain about the parameters and/or the right protocol? Which OBD hex commands are you trying to send there?

P.S. this should be a comment but due to a lack of reputation (50) i cannot make one...

**UPDATE**

If you get

> NO DATA

the ELM documentation states:

> Not all requests are supported by every vehicle. Yours may not have
>   data to give, or was never designed to respond to this PID (or SID).
>   If you are sure that the vehicle should be responding to this request,
>   then check that the ELM IC’s timeout has not been set too short. Try
>   issuing a AT ST FF command so the chip waits a full second before
>   declaring there is no data available. Maybe your ECU just has higher
>   priority things to attend to, and it is taking longer for it to answer
>   you.

Maybe some ECU is too slow in responding. Try the suggested command for the longer timeout and please report back. Also check the (eventually!) expected output for these ECUs if possible.

Comment: If it was due to wrong protocol settings I wouldn't have got response for 200 05 c0 00 10 00 03 01 1.

Comment: you are definitely right, i focused on the last part - sry for that. I updated the answer (is easier to read), check that please.

Comment: Yeah I did that, no change in response.

Comment: 2 more things: (1) are you really sure your car will answer with pid 768? Have you tried the typical [7E8 of the engine or main ECU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) first with mode 01 to see if the general responses for current data are working? (2) The first byte describes (as you know) the mode and there is no 'a0'. BTW you can find the supported PIDs for every mode by setting it '00'